# How can Load my UserControl using different threads?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm using .NET C# and trying to load a UserControl that contains three tabs. What I want to do is, to load the first Tab make it visible and responsive and then load the other two tabs in a background thread (or worker or task).

I've tried to do so using a thread, a task, a backgroundworker but always have the same exception "*The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.*"

here some code samples I used:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

in the bw_DoWork I put all the work I need to do that involves UI updates

```
Task t1 = new Task(DoWork);
t1.Start();
```

in the DoWork I do the same( some code with UI update)

Thanks for the help.

Oussema

Comment: Kindly add the code what you have tried, so that you can get your query resolved.

Comment: Constructing the controls should be a relatively cheap operation. Retrieving the data to put in them may not be. You should separate the two.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen in my case, it's constructing the controls that is very expensive, I've already optimized the data loading process.

Answer (score 2):

This is not impossible, but it is a bad idea - it's very tricky to get right.

Instead, you want to separate the business logic from the UI, so that you can do the logic in the background, while the UI is still on the UI thread. The key is that you must not modify the UI controls from the background thread - instead, you first load whatever data you need, and then either use `Invoke` or `ReportProgress` to marshal it back on the UI thread, where you can update the UI.

If creating the controls themselves is taking too long, you might want to look at some options at increasing the performance there. For example, using `BeginUpdate` and friends to avoid unnecessary redraws and layouting while you're still filling in the data, or creating the controls on demand (as they are about to be visible), rather than all upfront.

A simple example using `await` (using Windows Forms, but the basic idea works everywhere):

```
tabSlow.Enabled = false;

try
{
  var data = await Database.LoadDataAsync();

  dataGrid.DataSource = data;
}
finally
{
  tabSlow.Enabled = true;
}
```

The database operation is done in the background, and when it's done, the UI update is performed back on the UI thread. If you need to do some expensive calculations, rather than I/O, you'd simply use `await Task.Run(...)` instead - just make sure that the task itself doesn't update any UI; it should just return the data you need to update the UI.

Comment: thanks for the response. actually all I need to do is update a UI component. it is the slow part. so basically, I have loaded all the data I needed, I load the first tab, I wanna display it and let the other two tabs load the UI in background. So yes, it is the UI I wanna update, and not load the data.

Comment: @OussemaSlaimi Well, in that case, multi-threading isn't going to help you at all. You'll need to find other ways to improve the UI performance, as I noted in my answer. A viable option might also be to allow other UI operations in the middle of your UI updates, if you can handle the reentrancy (e.g. if you absolutely have to create thousands of buttons, you could inject `Application.DoEvents` every hundred buttons or so to keep the UI responsive, but make sure you understand what's actually happening).

Answer (score 0):

WPF does not allow you to change UI from the background thread. Only ONE SINGLE thread can handle UI thread. Instead, you should calculate your data in the background thread, and then call `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(...)` method to update the UI. For example:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => textBoxTab2.Text = "changing UI from the background thread");
```

Comment: this instruction doesn't compile on my code (wpf c# framework .net 4.5)

Comment: @OussemaSlaimi `textBoxTab2` - I assume that this is any TextBlock than has `x:Name="textBoxTab2"`, but here could be any logic that updates your UI.